# Data from Zap Trigger to Developer Action

Tags: javascript, quickbooks, zapier

I am working on a project for a client who uses a platform called Zapier. If you aren't familiar with it, this question probably won't make much sense... (unfortunately)

I am using a 'Zap' so that I can leverage the existing trigger for Quickbooks and then I have used their developer platform to build a private app that I am using as my action. All is well and good, the action works great BUT, I can't find any good documentation on how my action (since it is a custom developer app) can see data from the trigger. Obviously I need that data to pass to the API that my action calls out to and it seems like it should be very cut/dry but for whatever reason I am failing to find a good way to do this.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you asked Zapier customer support? That is probably the better channel for this question, since your question isn't specifically about programming.

Comment: I have but I haven't heard anything back.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on exactly what you are trying to do and which Quickbooks trigger you are using? If you are using the developer platform, then you will probably still have to "link up" the trigger to the action using a Zapier account, in other words, setting up a "Zap" using the Zapier UI. However, you may be better served using the "Code by Zapier" action, which takes either Javascript or Python and allows you to specify which data from the trigger you want to include.